# Why cant a certain networkshare on a Server 2012 cant be accessed with Win10 PC anymore?

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory

A week ago one user (UserA) on a certain PC (Workstation09) produced an error message when accessing a network share using its server's hostname(srv04). The share is still accessible using the server's IP (192.168.10.4).

There are multiple users in the same room with identical PCs and identical rights (same ACL/security groups). UserA can access the network share on srv04 on EVERY other workstation in the company. EVERY other User can access the network share on Workstation09.

I kicked the PC out of the domain, reconnected it using a different name, changed its IP and made an entry into the "hosts" file, and rebooted the server. Nothing helped.

I noticed in the event display, that UserA somehow started using the old domain to access the network share.(domain changed 6 years ago)

How can I change this back to the correct domain?

Event display

Account, for which the login failed:

Security-ID:NULL SID Account Name: UserA

Account Domain: "old domain"

Best regards

Comment: "the old domain"?

Comment: I can see in the event display, which domain has been used to access the networkshare. Under every other circumstance, there would be "domain-new", but for this user on only this particular pc its "domain-old".

Comment: Saved credentials? Check `control keymgr.dll`

Answer (score 0):

Does the user have a drive explicitly mapped to the "old" server? Maybe not even to the same share, but to something using the old server name or IP?

Run `net use` from the command line to check. I'd personally delete everything listed, reboot and remap them as needed. To delete connected network drives, run `net use \\[server]\[share] /delete`. To delete mapped drives, run `net use [driveletter]: /delete`.

If the drives get mapped via a logon script, check that the user doesn't have a custom one. Also, go to Credential Manager in the Control Panel and ensure the user doesn't have any cached Windows credentials. In the AD account properties, check `homeDirectory` and `scriptPath`, if you use those.

As a note, throwing things into the hosts file is generally pretty irrelevant if `nslookup` shows the client can resolve the correct hostname. Connecting via the IP shows that SMB is working to the server. If no-one else could connect to the server share from that same machine, it could indicate there was some problem with the workstation trust or Kerberos, or that the PC had a static IP that was being overlapped by another machine that acquired the same IP. If you haven't got rid of the hosts entry already, do it asap so it doesn't cause confusion later.

Comment: I've got an entry from 2016 in the credential management........deleted it and now it works.

Comment: Cool. It'd be good if you "accept" my answer to help others.